# Comparing multiple arrays for the same values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, matching

I have the following code that produces an array.

I need to split that array up and compare the resulting arrays against one another.

I only need to compare arrays that are next to one another in order.

So the first and second, second and third, so on.. I can build another array to store the order that needs to be compared if that helps. I just haven't a clue how to check them like this.

The goal is to ensure that the arrays on either side of one another do not contain the same $racer_id

It's for a scoring app for a race track and one racer can not be in races that are one after the other.

Can someone give me a shove in the right direction?

** there will only be one $event_id, with multiple $class_id and $racer_id.

```
<?php
function getEventClasses()
{
    global $db;
    global $event_id;
    try {
        $getEventClasses = $db->prepare('SELECT class_id
                                     FROM tbl_event_classes
                                     WHERE event_id = :event_id
                                     ORDER BY sort');
        $getEventClasses->bindValue(':event_id', $event_id);
        $getEventClasses->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo 'An Error occurred!<br>';
        //user friendly message
        $ex->getMessage();
        echo $ex;
        exit;
    }
    $eventClasses = [];
    while ($r = $getEventClasses->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $eventClasses[] = [
            'class_id' => $r['class_id']
        ];
    }
    return $eventClasses;
}

function getEntries($class_id)
{
    global $db;
    global $event_id;
    try {
        $getEntries = $db->prepare('SELECT tbl_event_entries.racer_id, 
                                   tbl_event_entries.class_id, 
                                   tbl_event_entries.event_id, 
                                   tbl_event_classes.class_type, 
                                   tbl_event_classes.points_class, 
                                   tbl_moto_order.moto_nbr
                            FROM tbl_moto_order 
                            INNER JOIN (tbl_event_entries 
                             LEFT JOIN tbl_event_classes 
                                    ON (tbl_event_entries.event_id = tbl_event_classes.event_id)
                                    AND (tbl_event_entries.class_id = tbl_event_classes.class_id)) 
                                    ON (tbl_moto_order.class_id = tbl_event_entries.class_id)
                                    AND (tbl_moto_order.event_id = tbl_event_entries.event_id)
                            WHERE tbl_event_entries.event_id = :event_id
                            AND tbl_event_entries.racer_id != "9999"
                            AND tbl_event_entries.class_id = :class_id');
        $getEntries->bindValue(':event_id', $event_id);
        $getEntries->bindValue(':class_id', $class_id);
        $getEntries->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo 'An Error occurred!<br>';
        //user friendly message
        $ex->getMessage();
        echo $ex;
        exit;
    }
    $eventEntries = [];
    while ($r = $getEntries->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $eventEntries[] = [
            'racer_id'     => $r['racer_id'],
            'class_id'     => $r['class_id'],
            'event_id'     => $r['event_id'],
            'class_type'   => $r['class_type'],
            'points_class' => $r['points_class'],
            'moto_nbr'     => $r['moto_nbr']
        ];
    }
    return $eventEntries;
}

$eventClasses = getEventClasses();
foreach ($eventClasses as $eventClass) {
    $eventEntries = getEntries($eventClass['class_id']);
    foreach ($eventEntries as $eventEntry) {
        $runningClasses[$eventClass['class_id']][] = [
            'racer_id'     => $eventEntry['racer_id'],
            'event_id'     => $eventEntry['event_id'],
            'class_type'   => $eventEntry['class_type'],
            'points_class' => $eventEntry['points_class'],
            'moto_nbr'     => $eventEntry['moto_nbr']
        ];
    }
}
foreach ($runningClasses as $class) {
    $f->printr($class);
}
?>
```

the array:

```
     Array
 (
     [17] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 95
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 17
                     [moto_nbr] => 3
                 )
             [1] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 350
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 17
                     [moto_nbr] => 3
                 )
             [2] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 493
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 17
                     [moto_nbr] => 3
                 )
             [3] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 295
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 17
                     [moto_nbr] => 3
                 )
             [4] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 1142
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 17
                     [moto_nbr] => 3
                 )
             [5] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 628
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 17
                     [moto_nbr] => 3
                 )
         )
     [14] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 1142
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [1] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 162
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [2] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 151
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [3] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 1176
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [4] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 401
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [5] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 264
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [6] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 797
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [7] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 124
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [8] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 29
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [9] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 74
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [10] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 117
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [11] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 408
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [12] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 501
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
             [13] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 1125
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 14
                     [moto_nbr] => 4
                 )
         )
     [8] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 1180
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 8
                     [moto_nbr] => 6
                 )
         )
     [16] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 73
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 16
                     [moto_nbr] => 12
                 )
             [1] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 9
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 16
                     [moto_nbr] => 12
                 )
             [2] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 525
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 16
                     [moto_nbr] => 12
                 )
         )
     [13] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 1089
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 13
                     [moto_nbr] => 15
                 )
             [1] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 73
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 13
                     [moto_nbr] => 15
                 )
             [2] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 162
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 13
                     [moto_nbr] => 15
                 )
             [3] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 264
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 13
                     [moto_nbr] => 15
                 )
             [4] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 797
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 13
                     [moto_nbr] => 15
                 )
             [5] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 422
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 13
                     [moto_nbr] => 15
                 )
             [6] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 1176
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 13
                     [moto_nbr] => 15
                 )
             [7] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 76
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 13
                     [moto_nbr] => 15
                 )
             [8] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 1136
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 13
                     [moto_nbr] => 15
                 )
         )
     [5] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 600
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => Y
                     [points_class] => 5
                     [moto_nbr] => 16
                 )
             [1] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 1143
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => Y
                     [points_class] => 5
                     [moto_nbr] => 16
                 )
         )
     [10] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 421
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 10
                     [moto_nbr] => 19
                 )
             [1] => Array
                 (
                     [racer_id] => 1219
                     [event_id] => 326
                     [class_type] => A
                     [points_class] => 10
                     [moto_nbr] => 19
                 )
         )
 )
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what is a race_track next to another?

Comment: hello, @indymx do you want to compare racer id's with in the one class id. for example first class id 17 has 4 sub entries, so you want to compare these four with one another and so on for next class id's...??

Comment: Juan a race track is a facility for racing motorcycles.

Comment: Manjeet. I'm only concerned with comparing the "class_id" array of the the current "class" and the one directly following. I'm going to add a "sort" field that will need to be changed in the event that there is duplicate "racer_id" within a test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First Answer

You can achieve this by comparing the current racer id with the next racer id in array ...

```
<?php 
$InputArray = array(
            17=>array(
                        0=>array(0=>95,1=>2 ),
                        1=>array(0=>350,1=>3),
                        2=>array(0=>493,1=>4),
                        3=>array(0=>493,1=>4)
                    ),
            18=>array(
                        0=>array(0=>56,1=>2 ),
                        1=>array(0=>89,1=>3),
                        2=>array(0=>52,1=>4)
                    ),
             );
```

Loop for comparing racer ID's

```
foreach($InputArray as $key => $val)
{
    foreach($val as $k => $v)
    {
        $nextKey =$k+1;
        if(array_key_exists($nextKey,$val))
        {
            if($v[0]==$val[$nextKey][0])
            {
                    echo "Racer ID ".$v[0]." Mathced in Class ID : ".$key;
                    ////sucess code here if same race id's are there...
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This will O/P

```
Racer ID 493 Mathced in Class ID : 17
```

As in the `$InputArray` racer id(493) at index 2 and 3 is same in class id 17

**[LIVE DEMO FOR THIS](https://eval.in/571972)**

## Modified Answer

```
$InputArray = array(
                17=>array(
                            0=>array('racer_id'=>95,'event_id'=>326 ),
                            1=>array('racer_id'=>350,'event_id'=>326),
                            2=>array('racer_id'=>493,'event_id'=>326),
                            3=>array('racer_id'=>1142,'event_id'=>326)
                        ),
                14=>array(
                            0=>array('racer_id'=>1142,'event_id'=>326),
                            1=>array('racer_id'=>162,'event_id'=>326),
                            2=>array('racer_id'=>151,'event_id'=>326)
                        ),
                 );
```

Array Looks like:

```
Array
(
    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [racer_id] => 95
                    [event_id] => 326
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [racer_id] => 350
                    [event_id] => 326
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [racer_id] => 493
                    [event_id] => 326
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [racer_id] => 1142
                    [event_id] => 326
                )

        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [racer_id] => 1142
                    [event_id] => 326
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [racer_id] => 162
                    [event_id] => 326
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [racer_id] => 151
                    [event_id] => 326
                )

        )

)
```

Find duplicate Id in two adjacent classes

```
$keys = array_keys($InputArray);///this will give you an array of all the class id's 17,14,8...      
foreach($InputArray as $key => $val)
{
    $racer_ids = array_map(function ($ar) {return $ar['racer_id'];}, $val);///get all the racers from current class
    $currentKey = array_search($key,$keys); ///get the key for current class in keys array
    if(array_key_exists($currentKey+1 ,$keys)) //check if next key exist in keys array (key for 14)
    { 
        $nextKey = $keys[$currentKey+1]; /// value present at next key in keys array 14 is the next key
        if(array_key_exists($nextKey,$InputArray)) ///check if next key present in $InputArray
        {
            $next_racer_ids = array_map(function ($ar) {return $ar['racer_id'];}, $InputArray[$nextKey]);///get all the racers from next class
            $result = array_intersect($next_racer_ids,$racer_ids);///compare racer ids from both array's  
            if(!empty($result)) ////return empty if racer_id is not same 
            {
                echo "SAME DRIVER";
                //your success code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://eval.in/579423)**

Comment: I'll try this later when I have a chance.

Comment: This is close, but not parsing the array deep enough. Your array is missing one level.

Comment: how ?? as you can see in class id 17 `array_key_exists()` is true for three times, it compares racer id of 0-1, 1-2 and 2-3

Comment: yes, it works with your dataset, but if you look at mine it's different. Each racer is an array within each class

Comment: @indymx, now take a look at code, mine data set is similar to yours... previously I've take index 'racer_id' but in your array you are not using any index so that's why it was confusing ...

Comment: Seems to work good.. Now I just have to implement the "success" code.. uggh.. ;)

Comment: yes you can ;) thank you for accepting my answer, glad to help you @indymx

Comment: @indymx thank you for accepting my answer, I need an up vote too ;):)

Comment: I finally got time to test this fix.. It's really not fixed. Your data doesn't look like mine. event_id will be the same in all records. That's not the value I need to test on, I need to see if rider_id is duplicated.

https://eval.in/579040

Comment: Also, you assume that the $nextKey will always be one higher than $key with $nextKey = $k+1.

My keys aren't like that at all. they can be pretty much any number.  So I need to actually find the real next key and test that way.

Comment: If you look at my data above you'll see exactly how the data I am pulling with my query looks. Your's does not look like mine at all. For clarity I added the key names in my class arrays

Comment: hello my friend @indymx , as you said that event_id in same for all classes, But we are not using `event_id` anywhere in this code so there is no issues about that ..

Comment: Either way, it's definitely not working. Look at my sample array, you'll see that in the array 17 and 14 has a duplicate rider_id that should trigger a positive, it does not

Comment: @indymx now take a look at my code and try this, I think this is what you are looking for,..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113338/discussion-between-indymx-and-manjeet-barnala).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure in PHP. But something like this

```
  for i = 0 to $eventClasses.count - 1 
  { 
      $event = $eventClasses[i];

      for j = 0 to $event.count -2 // last race doesnt compare with next
      {
          $currentEvent = $event[j]
          $nextEvent    = $event[j+1];

          if ($currentEvent[0] == $nextEvent[0] ) 
          {
              echo 'Same driver on next race?'
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Not sure if the last race from one event has to be compare with the first one of next event

Comment: event_id stays the same